# Why is my Tor browser not working?

Tags: ubuntu

I use a Ubuntu linux and I recently installed Tor and created a few .onion sites. When I first did this, I was able to pull them up with localhost on my normal internet or open the Tor browser and go to my .onion site and see it there.

After adding a few more .onion sites I was having some difficulty trying getting my Tor browser and localhost to work again. I know I had some trouble using `chown` to redirect my access and the Debian-Tor access and am afraid I messed that up and that is causing my blockage to the Tor browser.

I used Tor check to see if I am connected and it said yes. If you know where to do the `chown` to just give the right access to everyone or another trick to make sure I can use Tor again please let me know.

Basically, I need help figuring out why I cannot access my .onion sites. This is what my server looks like:

```
server {
    listen 127.0.0.1:8080;

    root /usr/share/nginx/www;
    index index.html index.htm;

    server_name hostname;

location / {
    allow 127.0.0.1;
    deny all;
}

}

server {
    listen 127.0.0.1:6667;

    root /usr/share/nginx/www;
    index1 index1.html index1.htm;

    server_name hostname;

    location / {
            allow 127.0.0.1;
            deny all;
    }

}

server {
    listen 127.0.0.1:22;

    root /usr/share/nginx/www;
    index2 index2.html index2.htm;

    server_name hostname;

    location / {
            allow 127.0.0.1;
            deny all;
    }

}
```

Comment: @stig atle steffensen could you please take the hold off now? I edited it.

Comment: reopened, thanks for taking the time to rewrite and edit the question. Much better now.

Comment: A couple of things to try: a) `nginx -t`, which will check whether the syntax of the config file is okay or not (it looks okay... ); b) Test the servers one at a time, by commenting out the other two. This might point to, for example, a missing index file. (Though I'm assuming all three different files are available in the root directory.)

Comment: (Without knowing what you've done with regards to `chown`-ing certain files/directories, it might be difficult to make other suggestions.)

Comment: it says that there is an error with /etc/nginx/nginx.conf (test failed). The only edits I made to that file are server_tokens off and adding error_log /dev/nul crit; and commenting out error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log; and access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;

Comment: Is that all the error message says? It doesn't point to a particular line, or give any more details? (Make sure you're running the tool with `sudo`.) What permissions does the file have? (On my setup it's 644, owned by root.)

Comment: nginx: [emerg] unknown directive "index1" in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default:21

|||

nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed

Comment: Those are the errors

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26410/discussion-between-richard-horrocks-and-theintern).